# How to Give keys and values of my created list to the map?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

```
public class HashMapTest2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Map<String,String> player = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.println("Enter number of Players");
        Integer p = Integer.valueOf(s.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter number of Teams");
        Integer t = Integer.valueOf(s.nextLine());

        List<String> listp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i<p; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter Player name "+i);
            listp.add(s.nextLine());
        }

        List<String> listt = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i<t; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter Team name "+i);
            listt.add(s.nextLine());
        }
        for (String str1 : listp){
            for (String str2 : listt){
                player.put(str1,str2);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("---------------");
        System.out.println(player);

    }
}
```

I want to assign the player name as keys and team name as values...
seems like i am not getting it properly.
I tried using for-each loop but it is giving me same value for every one...

Comment: You're putting in _every_ team entry for _every_ player. In essence the last entry of `listt` will be the team chosen for every player string in `listp`. When you put a new value in with the same key as before, you overwrite the previous value.

Comment: What are the input values you are giving? Do note if you are giving the same names for different teams the initial key gets replaced.

Comment: Please tell us what kind of output you want, because right now you cannot do what you want if the # of players and # of teams differ (they have to be the same size) by the definition of a map being 1-to-1 with respect to this problem.

Comment: @Water ok, So, forget about the nested loop that i created. i just want players as key and team name as value. SO, when l call the player name then its team name is also displayed.

Comment: @ParitoshBhatt Am I safe to assume that you are going to get the same # of players and teams? As in `p == t`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking following assumptions -

1. number of players and teams are same
2. We can randomly asssign any player to any team (there are no identifiers for the same)

You can try following code , if above mentioned assumptions are correct -

```
public class HashMapTest2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Map<String,String> player = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.println("Enter number of Players");
        Integer p = Integer.valueOf(s.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter number of Teams");
        Integer t = Integer.valueOf(s.nextLine());

        List<String> listp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i<p; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter Player name "+i);
            listp.add(s.nextLine());
        }

        List<String> listt = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i<t; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter Team name "+i);
            listt.add(s.nextLine());
        }
        for(int i=0;i<listp.size();i++) {
            player.put(listp.get(i), listt.get(i));
        }

        System.out.println("---------------");
        System.out.println(player);

    }
}
```